# Empty command with one optional argument after an equation causes an extra horizontal indentation

Tags: equations, optional-arguments, white-space

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand{\CMDI}[1]{}
\newcommand{\CMDII}[2][]{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        3.14
    \end{equation}
    \CMDII[optional]{main}
    A sentence which is so long that it does not fit on one line and continues on another line and which would be even longer if I was more creative.
    \begin{equation}
        3.14
    \end{equation}
    \CMDI{main}
    A sentence which is so long that it does not fit on one line and continues on another line and which would be even longer if I was more creative.
\end{document}
```

It gives the following pdf:

[image: PDF]

Why is there the extra white space before the first "A" and how can I remove it by modifying the definition of `\CMDII`? Thanks!

My motivation: I use a custom command with an optional argument to insert notes in the draft and don't want to display them in the final version while keeping them in the source code.

Comment: In your definitions, include `\ignorespaces` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. However, defining `\newcommand{\CMDII}[2]{\ignorespaces}` does not seem to solve the problem on my system.

Comment: Add a line ending `%`, as in `\CMDII[optional]{main}%`

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, it does indeed work, my coding was a bit strange. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the hint, but it was caused by a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a particular feature: TeX does some macro expansion when finishing a math display and in the second case `\CMDI{}` expands to nothing and disappears as if had never been there to begin with. Indeed, if you try with `\relax\CMDI{}`, the spurious space would appear.

Where does it come from? The expansion mentioned before is used to suppress the space created by the endline after `\end{equation}`. In the case of `\CMDII`, however, the command is not fully expandable, so the endline after `{}` produces a space.

Solution:

```
\newcommand{\CMDI}[1]{\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\CMDII}[2][]{\ignorespaces}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation!